# Refresh listview after click Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I have an Android app (created from tutorials) that creates a list from JSON and depending on the data it creates a yellow or black background.

What i want is when a person clicks on a item from the list, data is transmitted to a server (works)
But then i want to refresh my list because the data has changed (cannot get this to work) Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {
// url to make request
private static String url = "http://www.somesite.com/kaku/kaku_list.php/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_ONTVANGERS = "ontvangers";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_BESCHRIJVING = "beschrijving";
private static final String TAG_KANAAL = "kanaal";
private static final String TAG_NUMMER = "nummer";
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray ontvangers = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ontvanger = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        ontvangers = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ONTVANGERS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < ontvangers.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = ontvangers.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String beschrijving = c.getString(TAG_BESCHRIJVING);
            String kanaal = c.getString(TAG_KANAAL);
            String nummer = c.getString(TAG_NUMMER);
            String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_BESCHRIJVING, beschrijving);
            map.put(TAG_KANAAL, kanaal);
            map.put(TAG_NUMMER, nummer);
            map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            ontvanger.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new OntvangerAdapter(this, ontvanger,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {  TAG_BESCHRIJVING, TAG_ID, TAG_STATUS }, new int[] {
            R.id.beschrijving, R.id.Ontvanger_id, R.id.status});


    setListAdapter(adapter);
    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String Ontvanger_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Ontvanger_id)).getText().toString();
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String url1 = "http://www.somesite.com/kaku/action.php?id="+Ontvanger_id+"/" ;
            // getting JSON string from URL
            jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);



        }



    });


}

}
```

Comment: call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh listview.

Comment: that was what i thought but i can only select: adapter.notify() or" adapter.notify all().......... the method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter

Comment: it should refresh listview. that works for me all the time. check this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 1):

From your comments

ListAdapter does not have `notifyDataSetChanged()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

You will to use `ArrayAdapter` or `BaseAdapter`. Its better to use a Custom Listview with a Custom Adapter extending either ArrayAdapter of BaseAdapter.(you can customize listview items easily).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

`public void notifyDataSetChanged ()`

Added in API level 1

Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `notifyDataSetCHanged();` and it'll be good.

Comment: where do i need to put that method because i tried to implement that but i was not succesfull........... (beginner hhahahaah)

Comment: after your adapter initialization : `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: that was what i thought but i can only select:
adapter.notify()
or"
adapter.notify all()

Comment: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter

Comment: @user1836258 check my answer ListAdapter does not have `notifyDataSetChanged`. Use `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

To update the data/list in list view, you have to make a call to the method `notifyDataSetChanged();`

How and when to call that?
After you modify your `ontvanger` , call the function above.
Another side note, I think for newer API, you are not allowed to make HTTP request on UI thread anymore, you have to do it on AsyncTask or some background thread.

Hope that helps